# android adding facility to choose custom sound effects within an application

Tags: android, android-preferences, audio

I have an app that plays some sounds at certain points in the app's life cycle. I want to allow the user to customize these sounds (currently they are mp3 files residing in res/raw directory). I am looking at RingtonePreference but it is not clear how I can add new sounds to the values shown and then use them in my application. If someone can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

**EDIT**:

One way seems to be to add the file into the media store. Something like the code shown below. This does seem a bit overkill since now in the android manifest file you have to use the permission "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS". Ideally, I would like to just add the mp3 resources as options without writing them into the media store.

```
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        InputStream raw = getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.file_name);

        File f = new File("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.clock_ticking);
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, f.getAbsolutePath());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "TITLE");
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "artist");
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(f
                .getAbsolutePath());
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
```

**EDIT 2:**
Another way seems to be use list preferences. Although list preferences would work - you would have to manually "play" the sound when the selection changes. Let me see if that works or not and I would report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that worked for me is:

Use ListPreferences to create a dropdown. For this first create a string array file called sounds.xml in res/values folder (following assumes there are two options). The first array would show up as strings in your list preference and the second is the integer value mapped to it.

```
<string-array name="preferenceName">
    <item>Sound 1</item>
    <item>Sound 2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="preferenceValues">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
</string-array>
```

The list preference itself would look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Sound" >
        <ListPreference
            android:entries="@array/preferenceName"
            android:entryValues="@array/preferenceValues"
            android:key="preferenceName"
            />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Now we just need to be able to play the sound each time the user selects an option. That is done by adding an  OnPreferenceChangeListener  to the list preference widget. (see pseudo code below for the OnPreferenceChangeListener )

```
private OnPreferenceChangeListener onPreferenceChangeListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if "preferenceName".equals(preference
                    .getKey())) {

                //play the sound mapped to this preference here using
                            // media player
            }
            return true;
        }



    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Create some kind of file explorer (you can use the [File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html), same as regular Java, to create it) in order to allow the user to select a file and then use a `MediaPlayer` to play them.

**Edit:**

If you want to make it easier, ask your users to put them in a specified directory in the SD Card, say `yourapp/sounds`, then you can use a ListView to list all the files in that directory using something as:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/yourapp/sounds");
File[] sounds = f.listFiles();
for (File sound : sounds) {
    // Filter each one to see if it is a valid sound file
    // and then add them to a ListView where the user can choose them
}
```

Comment: Thanx Beowulf - but I suspect there may be a better solution than creating a file explorer for this. Please see my edit (I do not like that solution also since it requires a "Write" permission.

Comment: Take a look into my edit, restricting to a single directory will make it much easier - and won't require any kind of permission. `WRITE_SETTINGS` will make many people wonder what will it be used for :)

Comment: Thanx Beowulf. I agree WRITE_SETTINGS should not be used here. I think there should be a simple way to create a dropdown list of sounds from raw files. That would be the ideal solution

Comment: Hi Beowulf - using list preference and then playing a sound selectively from res/raw works fine  - please see the answer I posted.

Comment: I thought you wanted the user to be able to add a sound that he had in his device :)

Comment: No - I realized later that is what you thought as well  - sorry should have clarified:)- I do not want the user to upload any files - I have the set of mp3 files - I just want to give that set for each type of sound (basically the user should have some predefined set of choices for the sound effects)